# Creating diagonal matrix

Tags: matrix

B is an 6*6 diagonal matrix (diagonal elements = 0) and off-diagonal elements have a probability of 0.5 to take a random value, uniformly distributed, between 0 and 0.05

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. This reads like a homework assignment question. Please show what you have accomplished so far (include Mathematica code not an image) and indicate where you need further help.

Comment: Welcome to MmaSE. The community [expects the following](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from you
❌: A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal. No homework
❌: A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html). 
❌. An example of what you expect as output.
❌. Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge. 
❌. Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.